# Why do my embeds look like code on Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

I was trying to make a help embed page for my bot that I'm working on. However instead of embedding it shows this gibberish:

[image: As you see it doesn't even reply.]

The code that I used:

```
@client.command
async def help(ctx):
    print("ctx.message.author.avatar_url")
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Commands", description="Help Page", color=0xad1f1f)
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.message.author.name + "#" + ctx.message.author.discriminator, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name=".help", value="Shows this page. Do .help [Page] for more help pages", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=".say", value="Says what you input and removes your message. (Administrator Exclusive)", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name=".avatar", value="Sends your avatar. Or the avatar of anyone mentioned or replied to.", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="Page (1/1)")
    await ctx.message.reply(embed=embed)
```

I have tried everything. I have googled, made all the variables print in case there is something wrong with `avatar_url` for example. And I am simply tired of it now. Perhaps it was a syntax error and I am really stupid and I hope that's not the case.

Comment: That's the default help command, did you remove it before hand?

Comment: What? Is there a default help command? How

Comment: There always was a default help command, it's the one you're getting. You should first remove it (with `bot.remove_command("help")`) and then define your own help command. Though you should be getting an error like this: `'help' command is already registered`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default help command from discord.py. Disable it by adding right after defining your bot:

eg.:

```python
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", case_insensitive=True)
    client.remove_command('help')
```

Comment: `commands.Bot` has a `help_command` kwarg, so you can add `help_command=None` to disable the default one, making `client.remove_command()` useless.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to disable the help command according to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot.help_command) is to pass `help_command=None` into the constructor for `discord.ext.commands.Bot`, such as:

```py
bot = commands.Bot(help_command=None)
```